# How to convert requirejs script to nomal javascript?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, converters, simplify

How can I convert a script did based in requirejs to a normal javascript code?
for example:

`define("anything",['anything'], function(anything){
    //code
});`

how it will be in normal javascript code, without requirejs?
Have a form to convert it simple?

Comment: View the source of require.js and see what they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include your dependencies 's before using them in your implementation and then remove the requirejs define()'s.